# Prove that $P(A) \oplus P(B) \subseteq P(A \oplus B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove that $P(A) \oplus P(B) \subseteq P(A \oplus B)$

I uploaded a picture with my solution. what do you think about it? I really need to know if I have mistakes here or not so I can continue solving other Power Set more complicated questions.

P.S. I think in (II) whereas $(C \subseteq A) \cup (C \subseteq B)$ is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false, assuming $\oplus$ means symmetric difference (as suggested by the scanned work).

Set $A=\{1,2,4\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$.  Then $A\oplus B=\{1,3,4\}$.  Set $x=\{1,2\}$.  We have $x\subseteq A$, so $x\in P(A)$.  We have $x\nsubseteq B$, so $x\notin P(B)$.  Thus $x\in P(A)\setminus P(B)$, and so $x\in P(A)\oplus P(B)$.  However, $x\nsubseteq A\oplus B$, so $x\notin P(A\oplus  B)$.